# C# How to SELECT row n in EF6

Tags: c#, sql-server, select, entity-framework-6

How can I tell EF6 that I want the Second Row, or the 5th Row, or the N'th Row?
The Id of the rows are not sequential in that there are gaps as rows are removed etc...

Comment: This isn't a duplicate it is NOT asking for a range. The Solution is the same but the question is not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LINQ:

```
var person = context.Persons.Skip(5).Take(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Anyway you should set order for query and then LINQ helps you to do any query.
Next example shows hot to take the fifth row:

```
getDbContext()
      .Set<T>()
      .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
      .Skip(4)
      .Take(1);
```